# Meteor breadcrumb

Tags: meteor, iron-router

How do I implement a reactive breadcrumb with [Meteor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meteor_%28platform%29) and iron-router?

Now I'm looking for the current path, triggered by a reactive session variable and then adding each link that corresponds to that route inside the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) with [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can call `Router.current().path` inside a helper function and it will return the current path. Then split the path on `/` and return the array to your breadcrumbs template. The function is reactive, so updates will propagate:

```
Template.breadcrumbs.path = function() {
  return Router.current().path.split( "/" );
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't knew that Router.current() is reactive!

Answer (score 5):

With Meteor 1.0 and Iron.Router it would be:

```
Template.breadcrumbs.helpers({
  path: function() {
    return Router.current().route.path(this).split( "/" );
  }
});
```

Note that the way of adding methods to the template engine `Template.breadcrumbs.path = function() {}` is deprecated.

Comment: I created a more advanced plugin for meteor which works with the iron router to generate breadcrumbs: https://atmospherejs.com/monbro/iron-router-breadcrumb